# Wrong date showing in simulator of iPhone

Tags: ios, datetime, ios5

I am using this code

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"%@",today);
```

In console it is showing 
0024-03-06 07:51:46 +0000

Everything is ok except the year.It's showing wrong year(0024).It should be (2012). Can anyone tell me how shall I get correct code.

My mac system date is right.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please check your iPhone simulator calendar settings in `Settings -> General -> International -> Calendar ->`

Your current calendar is Japanese, if you set it to Gregorian then your problem will resolve.

and you also change it by using NSDateFormatter if you don't want to change your simulator settings -

```
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setCalendar:calendar];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
    NSLog(@"date = %@",[dateFormat stringFromDate:today]);
```